# Javascript text Resize

Tags: javascript, text, resize

Without getting into the "should a text resizer be used or not" debate, I'd like some help with this...suffice to say that my clientele are from and older generation and may be sight impaired...

My script isn't functioning, and I'm not sure why.  It's not live yet, so here's what I'm working with:

```
   function fsize(size,unit,id){
     var vfontsize = document.getElementById("#colleft");
     if(vfontsize){
      vfontsize.style.fontSize = size + unit;
     }
   }
   var textsize = 14;
   function changetextsize(up){
     if(up){
      textsize = parseFloat(textsize)+2;
     }else{
      textsize = parseFloat(textsize)-2;
     }
   }
```

I'm using onclick events to trigger the size changes.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: One of the things I hope that the popularity of Stackoverflow can accomplish is to raise awareness that when asking why something "doesn't work", it's **vitally important** to describe what *does* happen: what errors are reported, what incorrect effects are seen, what things are supposed to happen but mysteriously don't, etc etc. I'm probably just a hopeless romantic, however.

Comment: @Pointy - Abandon hope all ye who enter here

Comment: @DVK of course!  But my experience, which I'm sure is not unique, is that this has been something I've dealt with for my entire career: from college kids in my assembly language class to co-workers asking questions about our products. "I tried that, and it didn't work."  - *pause for effect* "Well what exactly happened that made you conclude that it 'didn't work'?" - "Oh well I got a null pointer exception ..." <<sigh>>

Answer (score 0):

1) You are not using "id" parameter in fsize()

2) Please post your onclicks... how are you using fsize and changetextsize together? You don't seen to be using "textsize" value anywhere ... Also, what happens when you click?

Answer (score 0):

```
var vfontsize = document.getElementById("#colleft");
```

should, most likely, be

```
var vfontsize = document.getElementById("colleft"); // no hash
```

it seems to me like remnants from a jquery attempt or similar..

and then, tell us how you are calling these functions you have posted..